# Can any pattern be sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can any pattern be sequence ?
like $2$, $e$, $\pi$, $13$, $12$, $67$ ... can be considered as sequence?

I've read that we consider only those pattern as sequence in which we can predict the next term.
Please elaborate this thing in details .

Comment: What is your definition of *sequence*?

Comment: Is 1, 2, ... a sequence?  Can you predict the next term?

Comment: The usual definition of a sequence doesn't imply a rule generating the sequence necessarily.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sequence is simply a function from $\Bbb{N}$ to some set (in this case, $\Bbb{R}$). That is, every number in $\Bbb{N}$ needs to be assigned a single number in $\Bbb{R}$. There's no requirement that there be a nice formula for these sequences. In fact, some sequences can be defined, but are mathematically impossible to compute (e.g. the sequence of digits of an [uncomputable number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant)).

With that in mind, I'd say that $2, e, \pi, 13, 12, 67 \ldots$ is not really a sequence, because not every natural number is assigned an element of $\Bbb{R}$. Assuming you start $\Bbb{N}$ at $1$, you've only assigned values for $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$. There are, in fact, infinitely many sequences that start in this same way, and you haven't sufficiently specified which one.

Defining sequences with ellipses in this way, e.g. $1, 2, 5, 10, 17, 26, 37, 50, 65, \ldots$, is not exactly kosher. By specifying enough terms for a sufficiently simple formula, you decrease the risk that the reader will fail to grasp the sequence you're trying to specify, but it's much better to simply write $n^2 + 1$ instead, or more precisely, $(n^2 + 1)_{n=0}^\infty$. With a general formula, there's no chance that whatever pattern you're trying to convey could be missed.

If you don't have a general formula, then it's very important to still be able to properly identify the sequence that you're talking about. Essentially, you need to be talking about a sequence which satisfies certain conditions, and for which you know for a fact that no other sequence satisfies these conditions.

The most straight forward example of this is recursively defined sequences. For example, $a_0 = 1$ and for all $n \ge 1$, $a_n = \sin(n) + n$. This doesn't tell me the terms of the sequence, but I know that there is one and only one sequence that satisfies these conditions. In this way, I don't have a general formula, but I am referring to a single sequence.

EDIT: Looking over this answer again, I'm not particularly happy with it, but I don't know how to improve it. I just want to acknowledge how confusingly fine the line is between:

1. Specifying a few of the terms, but failing to specify a single sequence (as in what you did),
2. Clearly specifying a single sequence, but having no formula for the terms, and
3. Specifying a sequence by giving a general formula for the terms.

Whoever told you that sequences had to have a pattern was probably trying to warn you that an ellipsis "definition" like the one you gave needs to have a pattern, otherwise it's entirely unclear which of the many sequences with those numbers at the start you are referring to.

But, mathematically speaking, ellipsis "definitions" are dodgy, as they require some degree of mind-reading by the reader. Also, "patterns" are not a mathematical concept, but a psychological phenomenon. The reader takes in information, then fits it into a hierarchy of concepts in their mind, based on a personal aesthetic judgement of "simplicity".

For example, if somebody defined the terms $0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots$ (starting from $0$), you would instantly think it was the constant sequence $0$, because in your mind, that would be the "simplest" pattern that fit the sequence so far. Your mind would be less likely to think $n(n - 1)(n - 2)(n - 3)$, which also begins with $0, 0, 0, 0$, simply because your mind judges it to be less simple. It's somehow less of a "pattern" for it, despite the fact that both sequences are equally valid mathematically. There's no mathematical sense in which $n(n - 1)(n - 2)(n - 3)$ is "simpler" than the constantly $0$ sequence.

My point is, the idea of patterns and pattern-matching are psychological phenomena. Mathematical definitions don't care about psychological phenomena. There's no requirement that there be a pattern. As I said earlier, there's no need for it to be computable. That is, it may be the case that there is no possible algorithm/method to compute the terms of the given sequence. It's not *quite* the same as leaving them unspecified (this is the brutally fine line I was talking about); they exist, but we literally **cannot** figure out what they are (and we are certain that there is no way to do so). If you take one of these sequences and ask, is the hundredth term $65$, there is a true/false answer to this question (because the sequence is well-defined), but there may be no possible way for anyone to know this answer.

That's really the difference here: there is a correct answer as to what is the next number, but it may not be known, or even knowable. The start of your sequence $2, e, \pi, 13, 12, 67 \ldots$ doesn't indicate any one number next. Mathematically speaking, there is no answer to "what is the next number?". It's not that there is an unknown answer, or that there is an answer, but it isn't expressible by a formula, but, in fact, there is no answer. That what makes your sequence undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, which is why "predict the next term" without further restrictions is often a crapshoot.

A sequence doesn't necessarily have to be numbers either, it can be ordered series of any mathematical object.

Comment: If you read "Mathematics Made Difficult" there is a section on "guess the next number" problems.  The recommended solution is to choose your favorite number and subtract 2.

Comment: Downvote: care to explain why you think my answer is not useful?

Comment: It wasn't from me!